# How do I convert a string of a named color to a Xamarin.Forms.Color?

Tags: xamarin.forms, colors

Given a string like "Red" or "yellow" how do I convert it to a valid Xamarin.Forms.Color?

I was using reflection to get the properties of Color and iterating through them comparing my string to the ToString of the property, but that is no longer working as the list of properties no longer contains all of the named colors (using Forms 5.0 pre-3)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example for more details? If from xaml you can use a value converter with a switch statement.

Comment: You could use [ColorTypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ColorTypeConverter?view=xamarin-forms),like  `var converter = new ColorTypeConverter();
            label.TextColor = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString("Red");`